# Worklight Sencha Touch 2 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create an app  using Sencha touch 2 in worklight environment.Sencha touch 2 uses MVC pattern , so how can i implement mvc in worklight ?

I have tried all solutions on the net and it dosent work.

Can you help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the attached project* to see the structure of a Sencha Touch 2 MVC type of project in Worklight.

[Worklight Sencha Touch 2-based MVC project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3bsrt5v1gyiz5r/Worklight506_Sencha2DemoProj.zip)

- Note that this project is based on Worklight 5.0.6 and fails migration to newer versions of Worklight, but this does not matter. Just take a look at the code.